# EnsureLocalDisposalRule of Gendarme and WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, gendarme

I have faced issue with the rule EnsureLocalDisposalRule when my code is incompatible with the rule.

Example of code:

```
Form myForm = new myForm { MdiParent = this };
myForm .Show();
```

It is brakes the rule and I corrected it like this

Example of code:

```
using (Form myForm = new myForm { MdiParent = this })
{
   myForm .Show();
}
```

But I have problem with my working code because after the above correction my `WinForm object` is destroyed right away.

How to fix the rule and get the code working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most static analysis tools have a significant flaw - they're only working on general patterns, and they often don't handle all of the "valid" exceptions to their rules.  There are almost always *valid* exceptions to the rules built into the static analysis rule engines.

In this case, you can't (and shouldn't) dispose of the form when using `.Show()`.  The form will get disposed correctly when it is closed.  This is effectively a "false" error, in this specific case.

In this case, you should ignore this specific error, as it's a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

The below change would work.

myForm .**ShowDialog**();

Since it opens the form as model dialog it will halt the program execution.